# Error while terminating EC2 instance: Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I get the following error while the play: `Terminate instances` is run:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Either region or ec2_url must be specified"}
```

This is my playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  remote_user: test
  gather_facts: no

  vars_files:
    - files/aws_creds.yml
    - files/info.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Basic provisioning of EC2 instance
      ec2:
        assign_public_ip: no
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_id }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_key }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        image: "{{ standard_ami }}"
        instance_type: "{{ free_instance }}"
        key_name: "{{ ssh_keyname }}"
        count: 3
        state: present
        group_id: "{{ secgroup_id }}"
        wait: no
        #delete_on_termination: yes
        instance_tags:
          Name: Dawny33Template
      register: ec2

    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        groupname: launched
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

## Here lies the SSH code
    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      wait_for:
        host: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        port: 22
        delay: 60
        timeout: 320
        state: started
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

- name: Configure instance(s)
  hosts: launched
  become: True
  gather_facts: True
  #roles:
  #  - my_awesome_role
  #  - my_awesome_test
  tasks:
    - name: install  git
      yum: name=git state=present
    - name: check out a git repository
      git: repo={{ repo_url }} dest=/Dest/To/Repo/ accept_hostkey=yes
      vars:
        repo_url: https://github.com/lorin/mezzanine-example.git

- name: Terminate instances
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Terminate instances that were previously launched
      ec2:
        state: 'absent'
        instance_ids: '{{ ec2.instance_ids }}'
```

**What does the error really means?  And, how do I solve it?**

Comment: You need to specify region in the terminate ec2 task

Comment: @BenWhaley I did add: `region: 'us-west-2'` under the instance_ids line. It throws this error: `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials"}` :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fire questions at very high rate... It's good to spend some time understanding what's going on.

I see you include `aws_creds.yml` for the first play when you launch instances, and don't define any vars files in the last play...

Comment: Thank You.  Sorry about that. We're hacking on a quick POC.  Yeah, I need to read the docs in detail properly :)